# Linq XElement changes Value formatting in foreach

Tags: .net, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

This seems like a strange one (unless I am missing something obvious).  I have to store this string:

```
{TestField1:=TestAltField1}{TestField2:=TestAltField2}
```

in an XML Value field resulting in something like this:

```
<ResultFieldAlias>{TestField1:=TestAltField1}{TestField2:=TestAltField2}</ResultFieldAlias>
```

The value is to be stored in string,string dictionary.  But when I try to pull it out of the XElements of XElement "XML" in a foreach loop and reflections, it changes the brackets and drops the colon resulting in this:

```
[TestField1, TestAltField1][TestField2, TestAltField2]
```

Here is the code I am using to get the properties via Reflections:

```cs
PropertyInfo[] properties = GetPublicProperties();

//loop through each entry in the dictionary and try to find its matching property
foreach (XE xe in XML.Elements())
{
    //Try to find a matching prop to this key
    PropertyInfo prop = properties.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Name.ToLower() == xe.Name.ToString().ToLower());

    if (prop != null)
        if (prop.PropertyType == typeof(bool))
            prop.SetValue(this, bool.Parse(xe.Value), null);
        else if (prop.PropertyType == typeof(FontSettings))
            prop.SetValue(this, new FontSettings(xe), null);
        else if (prop.PropertyType == typeof(Dictionary<string, string>))
            prop.SetValue(this, MyExtension.Deserialize(xe.Value), null);
        else
            prop.SetValue(this, xe.Value, null);
}
```

Note the Deserialize function that is expecting the format with the curlies and the :=.  When I debug it, I get this from the immediate window if I look at the xe object in the loop:

```
? xe
<ResultFieldAlias>[TestField1, TestAltField1][TestField2, TestAltField2]</ResultFieldAlias>
    base {System.Xml.Linq.XContainer}: <ResultFieldAlias>[TestField1, TestAltField1][TestField2, TestAltField2]</ResultFieldAlias>
    FirstAttribute: null
    HasAttributes: false
    HasElements: false
    IsEmpty: false
    lastAttr: null
    LastAttribute: null
    Name: {ResultFieldAlias}
    name: {ResultFieldAlias}
    NodeType: Element
    Value: "[TestField1, TestAltField1][TestField2, TestAltField2]"
```

BUT, if I create a brand new XElement based off the Last element of the XML (where it happened to land, there are a bunch before it), I get the right formatting:

```
? XElement xe1 =  XML.Elements().Last();
<ResultFieldAlias>{TestField1:=TestAltField1}{TestField2:=TestAltField2}</ResultFieldAlias>
    base {System.Xml.Linq.XContainer}: <ResultFieldAlias>{TestField1:=TestAltField1}{TestField2:=TestAltField2}</ResultFieldAlias>
    FirstAttribute: null
    HasAttributes: false
    HasElements: false
    IsEmpty: false
    lastAttr: null
    LastAttribute: null
    Name: {ResultFieldAlias}
    name: {ResultFieldAlias}
    NodeType: Element
    Value: "{TestField1:=TestAltField1}{TestField2:=TestAltField2}"
```

What gives?  Thanks.

**UPDATE:**

To answer Jeffs comment and add info, the XML object (XElement) is passed to this function.  The TestFields are added using the Add method of a string,string dictionary called "ResultFieldAlias" which is then converted to a string using this function before being wrapped by the XML tag "ResultFieldAlias":

```cs
public static string Serialize(Dictionary<string, string> data)
{
    if (data == null) 
        return null;

    return "{" + String.Join("}{", data.Select(c => c.Key + ":=" + c.Value).ToArray()) + "}";
}
```

The result is as follows (only the tail end of it - it would be huge to post):

```
<Callouts>
    .....
    .....   
  <ResultExceedFont>
    <FontSettings>
      <FontName>Curlz MT</FontName>
      <FontColor>#FF6B8E23</FontColor>
      <FontSize>15</FontSize>
      <FontUnderline>false</FontUnderline>
      <FontBold>false</FontBold>
      <FontItalic>true</FontItalic>
    </FontSettings>
  </ResultExceedFont>
  <ResultFieldAlias>{TestField1:=TestAltField1}{TestField2:=TestAltField2}</ResultFieldAlias>
</Callouts>
```

The two previous code pastes I have from my Immediate window in VS (with the ? at the start of the start) are taken at a Break at line "prop.SetValue(this, MyExtension.Deserialize(xe.Value), null);" so they are hitting the same XML object at the same time.  Here is the exact cut and paste (again, shorted the XML dump):

```
? XML
....
  <ResultExceedFont>
    <FontSettings>
      <FontName>Curlz MT</FontName>
      <FontColor>#FF6B8E23</FontColor>
      <FontSize>15</FontSize>
      <FontUnderline>false</FontUnderline>
      <FontBold>false</FontBold>
      <FontItalic>true</FontItalic>
    </FontSettings>
  </ResultExceedFont>
  <ResultFieldAlias>{TestField1:=TestAltField1}{TestField2:=TestAltField2}</ResultFieldAlias>
</Callouts>
    FirstAttribute: null
    HasAttributes: false
    HasElements: true
    IsEmpty: false
    lastAttr: null
    LastAttribute: null
    Name: {Callouts}
    name: {Callouts}
    NodeType: Element
    Value: "falsefalsefalsefalsefalsefalsefalsefalsefalsefalsefalsefalsefalsefalse[TestField1, TestAltField1][TestField2, TestAltField2]falsefalseBalloonfalse#FFFFFF00Adobe Song Std#FF228B2210truetruetrueAdobe Ming Std#FFF0808010truetruetrueAdobe Kaiti Std#FFDC143C20truefalsetrueCurlz MT#FF6B8E2315falsefalsetrue{TestField1:=TestAltField1}{TestField2:=TestAltField2}"
?xe
<ResultFieldAlias>[TestField1, TestAltField1][TestField2, TestAltField2]</ResultFieldAlias>
    base {System.Xml.Linq.XContainer}: <ResultFieldAlias>[TestField1, TestAltField1][TestField2, TestAltField2]</ResultFieldAlias>
    FirstAttribute: null
    HasAttributes: false
    HasElements: false
    IsEmpty: false
    lastAttr: null
    LastAttribute: null
    Name: {ResultFieldAlias}
    name: {ResultFieldAlias}
    NodeType: Element
    Value: "[TestField1, TestAltField1][TestField2, TestAltField2]"
?XML.Elements().Last()
<ResultFieldAlias>{TestField1:=TestAltField1}{TestField2:=TestAltField2}</ResultFieldAlias>
    base {System.Xml.Linq.XContainer}: <ResultFieldAlias>{TestField1:=TestAltField1}{TestField2:=TestAltField2}</ResultFieldAlias>
    FirstAttribute: null
    HasAttributes: false
    HasElements: false
    IsEmpty: false
    lastAttr: null
    LastAttribute: null
    Name: {ResultFieldAlias}
    name: {ResultFieldAlias}
    NodeType: Element
    Value: "{TestField1:=TestAltField1}{TestField2:=TestAltField2}"
```

Comment: LINQ to XML will not make such changes to the data. The problem is in how you parse it.  How is `XML` being initialized?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NEVERMIND!  Ahhh..stupid....it tuns out that I did not filter properly when building XML and added the ResultFieldAlias dictionary TWICE.  The first instance was created by the default ToString() method of the dictionary - hence the formatting.  So the xe var grabbed that one because it was first but my .Last() test grabbed the second, correct version.

Sorry for the useless post. Thanks Jeff for making me take a close look.

Ernie